# Using Jquery to prevent a "Submit Button" from posting data if a field is left blank

Tags: c#, jquery, html

So I'm putting together a little registration area for my web project, here. The user inputs various strings such as "Username", "Password", etc.

I already have a bit of code set up in order to prevent duplicate Usernames or Passwords in the database. I also have a guard in place if the "Password" and "Repeat Password" fields don't match.

What I'm trying to do now is to -

1: If the user attempts to Submit data while a field is blank, it will not post.

2: Display a "Fields cannot be blank" div I've assigned "display: none" to.

I was thinking something along the lines of assigning the input fields a class of "Required", and using some sort of code such as

if  == null
.show;
return false; //To prevent the rest of the function (the submit button posting to login/register) from firing.

Running into obscene problems. Anyway. Here's what I have so far.

```
$("#SubmitButton").click(function () { //Click Submit
            if ($("#PassReg").val() != ($("#PassConfirm").val())) { //Both fields match
                $("#PasswordMismatch").show(); //Or this div shows you messed up
                return false; //And nothing else fires
            }


            $.post("login/register", $('#ConfirmPanel *').serialize(), function (result) {

                if (result == 2) //Json return from C#
                    $("#UsernameInUse").show(); //Shows an error div
                else if (result == 3) //Json return from C#
                    $("#EmailInUse").show(); //Shows an error div
                else {
                    $("#ConfirmPanel").dialog('close'); //Closes the registration dialog
                }

            });
        });
```

Any thoughts? At first I thought that I literally -cannot- use "class" to mark an input field, and then have that input field compared to a null value. I don't know, though.

Comment: Ignore that bit about "if==null.show". I didn't use the proper code tags and it got fubared. Basically I wanted to select the "Required" class, compare that class .val to null, and if it's null, then display an error div and kill the submit function.

Comment: Avoid reinventing the wheel; use the [jQuery Validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation) and the [jQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `.submit()` jquery event handler on the form instead of `.click()` on the button. Then return false to prevent the normal form submission if needed.

Comment: Yes, definitely use ``.submit()`` instead of ``.click()`` in case they trigger the submit some other way!

Comment: Thanks for that info. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to `submit` the `form` using `$.post` you should stop the default behavior of the form submit by alwasy returning `false` from submit button click handler.

```
$("#SubmitButton").click(function () { //Click Submit
            if ($("#PassReg").val() != ($("#PassConfirm").val())) { //Both fields match
                $("#PasswordMismatch").show(); //Or this div shows you messed up
                return false; //And nothing else fires
            }


            $.post("login/register", $('#ConfirmPanel *').serialize(), function (result) {

                if (result == 2) //Json return from C#
                    $("#UsernameInUse").show(); //Shows an error div
                else if (result == 3) //Json return from C#
                    $("#EmailInUse").show(); //Shows an error div
                else {
                    $("#ConfirmPanel").dialog('close'); //Closes the registration dialog
                }

            });

            return false;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery way of preventing form submission is to use `preventDefault()`, like:

```
$("#SubmitButton").click(function (event) { //Click Submit
        if ($("#PassReg").val() != ($("#PassConfirm").val())) { //Both fields match
            $("#PasswordMismatch").show(); //Or this div shows you messed up
            event.preventDefault(); //And nothing else fires
            return;
        }

        //...
});
```

However, since you are posting the form asynchronously when validation passes, what you really want is something more along the lines of:

```
$("#SubmitButton").click(function (event) { //Click Submit
        event.preventDefault();  //we don't ever want to allow the default behavior
        if ($("#PassReg").val() != ($("#PassConfirm").val())) { //Both fields match
            $("#PasswordMismatch").show(); //Or this div shows you messed up
            return;
        }

        //post the form
});
```

The rest of what you suggest (using a class to mark each required input field, checking them all for empty strings) is reasonable.

Be aware that because you are binding the button's `click` event instead of the form's `submit` event it is entirely possible for the user to submit your form without ever clicking on your button and triggering your validation code.  For instance, by pressing return from any one of your text fields.

Also note that in this case you may find it more convenient to just use a traditional `onsubmit` directive on the form, like:

```
<form onsubmit="validateAndPost(); return false;">
    <!-- inputs and buttons, etc. -->
</form>

<script>
    function validateAndPost() {
        if ($("#PassReg").val() != ($("#PassConfirm").val())) { //Both fields match
            $("#PasswordMismatch").show(); //Or this div shows you messed up
            return;
        }

        //post the form
    }
</script>
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/AwxGE/

Answer (score 0):

I admire your desire to use jquery, however I would advise using a normal ASP.NET [ReqiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) control. As well as making your page substantially more concise and easy to maintain, it also allows you to very simply invoke server-side validation:

```
public void submitbutton_click(object sender, EventArgs args){
    Page.Validate();
    if(Page.IsValid){
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

Please don't reinvent the wheel, and don't trust the browser to behave as you think it will.

Comment: I agree 100% that server-side validation is key here, but this is just some "no blank fields" nonsense I'm trying to stomp out. I'll worry about the final product much later in the project's life.

Comment: Adding RequiredFieldValidators would have taken less time than asking the question...

Comment: client side validation should always be in addition to server side, but it produces a nicer user experience, especially on slow connections.

Comment: ASP.NET's standard validators include client-side validation by default!

Answer (score 0):

use this -

```
$(document).on('click', '#SubmitButton', function () { 
`enter code here`
});
```